# I found a Credit Union Share Certificate and a CU IRA certificate from my days of teaching in 1989 in Tacoma Washington

Tags: credit-unions

The credit union has since changes hands or closed down. How do I find out if these certificate still have value?

Comment: When did you stop actively using the Credit Union checking/savings account?  If it was long after the certificates time period, then it is likely that the money was returned to your account, and the question is about how to find an abandoned account.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot track down the history of the credit union and determine who owns it or what happened to it's assets, your best bet is likely to contact your state department of revenue and try to determine if your accounts were turned over as unclaimed property:

https://www.tre.wa.gov/portfolio-item/unclaimed-property-where-to-go/